# Mock a custom Toast in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, junit5

I am new to the Mocking Framework, I had been trying to mock a custom Toast for my application.
Her is the code for it :

```
   fun buildToastMessage(context: Context, message: String): Boolean {
       try {
       val mToast = Toast(context)
val inflater: LayoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as 
                                                                                            LayoutInflater
    val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_view, (context as Activity).findViewById(R.id.toast_container))
                   layout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.toast_text).text = message
                   mToast.apply {
                       setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                       duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                       view = layout
                       show()
                   }
                   return true
               } catch (e: Exception) {
                   e.printStackTrace()
               }
```

It Used the Mockito framework and I am not able to access the inner functionalities of the function during the test. I get a error message.

```
  

@Test
   fun `Testing Toast Message`() {

       `when`(mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).thenReturn(inflater)
       val actual = mViewHelper.buildToastMessage(mContext, "Toast Message")
       assertEquals(true, actual)

   }
```

And My Test fails and This is the log that I get :

> 

```
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:120)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:146)
        at com.adaptavant.yoco.unittest.helper.ViewHelperTest.Testing Toast Message(ViewHelperTest.kt:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
```

Comment: I'm guessing ``buildToastMessage`` returns ``false`` at the end, i.e. if an exception occurred? What's causing it?

Comment: In the real application the Toast is showing. But I need to unit test this Method using Mockito.

Comment: Yeah but the method is returning false because the stuff in your ``try`` block is throwing an exception (otherwise it would reach the ``return true`` line). So look at your logs (you're printing the stack trace when you catch the exception) and see what's causing it to fail. It could be a lot of things and that will help you narrow it down